# Forcing jPlayer buffering bar on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jplayer, buffering

I noticed that jPlayer doesn't keep showing its buffering bar on some mobile devices and this issue makes the user thinks the media is not loading. I searched here and didn't find anything related. So I'm posting an answer to this question with a link to a new jquery.jplayer.min.js containing the correction that I've made. The new lines forces the "buffering gif" be showed until the media start playing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to download the correction:

** https://pastebin.com/YS7UHNVA **

Here is the modification needed:

```
    seeked:function(){ (this.css.jq.seekBar.length&&this.css.jq.seekBar.removeClass("jp-seeking-bg"),this.removeStateClass("seeking")); if(this.css.jq.duration.text()=='00:00'){ this.css.jq.seekBar.addClass("jp-seeking-bg"); this.addStateClass('seeking');  }}
```